# Need to access AsyncTask value in Main Class

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am facing an issue in Async task, can anyone please suggest me any solution.
I have downloaded this example from this link :
[Source](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/10-1-inch-hdmi-input-lcd-monitor-12V/720526553.html)

My Current Structure is

- Main Class extends MyTask and implements AsyncTaskCompleteListener interface.
- AsyncTaskCompleteListener is an Interface contains the onTaskComplete Method .
- MyTask extends Async Task and onPostExcute contains CallBackMethod which will return the result-set got from the doInBackground.
- Http Class(Utils) contains the Http connection and returns the Result-set to AsyncTaskComleteListner from PostExecute.

I am trying to get my result-set Value in the main class from the interface method to perform my further operation.
I tried to get the value from static variables, static method but non of them worked, and also tried with creating a new class object to send and receive the result but every time it gives me **NullPointerException** . Because the statement written after the  AsyncTask gets executes before getting the result.

I have also tried to get the Status of asyncTask from its method getStaus(), but it returns only Running and dose not notify when the task is completed or finished.

Here is the code sample:

**Main Class Code :**

```
package com.example.androidasynctask;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AsyncTaskCompleteListener {

public static String[] asyncResult;
String res[] = null;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void btnclick(View view) {
    /*MyTask asyncTask = new MyTask(this);
    String [] asyncTaskResult = asyncTask.execute("fetchCategory.php","1%Id%1");*/

    //AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> asyncTaskRes = new MyTask(this).execute("fetchCategory.php","1%Id%1");
    //new MyTask(this).execute("fetchCategory.php","1%Id%1");
    MyTask asyncTask = (MyTask) new MyTask(this).execute("fetchCategory.php","1%Id%1");

     if(asyncTask.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) || asyncTask.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.PENDING)) {
         asyncTask.execute();
     }
     else {

         Log.v("In Else","Get Value");
     }



}

@Override
public void onTaskComplete(String[] result) {
    Log.v("IN ON TASK COMPLETE","VALUE = "+result[1]);


}



/*@Override
public void onTaskComplete(String result) {
    System.out.println("calling onTaskComplete SIMPLE....");
    System.out.println("result :: "+ result);
}*/

public static class GetAsyncResult
{
    static String[] returnValues;


    public GetAsyncResult()
    {}
    public GetAsyncResult(String[] res)
    {

        returnValues = res;
        Log.v("getResultSetValues","returnValues"+returnValues[1]);
    }


    public void getResultSetValues()
    {
        Log.v("getResultSetValues","returnValues"+returnValues[1]);


    }

}

}
```

**Async Task Code :**

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {

private Activity activity;
private ProgressDialog dialog;
private AsyncTaskCompleteListener callback;
public String[] asyncResultSetValue = null;
public MyTask(Activity act) {
    Log.v("MY TASK","ACTIVITY"+act);
    this.activity = act;
    this.callback = (AsyncTaskCompleteListener)act;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    Log.v("MY TASK","in ON PRE EXECUTE");
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    dialog.show();
}

@Override
protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
    Log.v("MY TASK","DO IN BACKGROUND");
    Log.v("PARAMS"," params[0] = "+params[0]+ "| params[1]"+params[1]);
    asyncResultSetValue = Utils.process_query(params[0],params[1]);
    return asyncResultSetValue;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    Log.v("MY TASK","in ON POST EXECUTE");
    if (null != dialog && dialog.isShowing()) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
    callback.onTaskComplete(result);
}

}
```

**HTTP CLASS CODE :**

```
 public class Utils {

    static String result = null;
    String endResult;
    static java.io.InputStream  is = null;
    static StringBuilder sb=null;
    static String delimiter = "\\|";            
    static String delimiter1 = "\\%";
    static String[] temp = null;
    static String[] temp1 = null;
    static ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
    static Context context;
    static ProgressDialog mDialog;
    static HttpResponse response;
    static String[] resultset_value = null;
    //static String url = "http://fortuneworkinprogress.in/News_App/";  //Global URL
    static String url = "http://10.0.2.2/News_App/";    //Global URL
    static String query_type,parameter;     

    /*************** PROCESS QUERY START  ***************/
      public static String[] process_query(String str_url, String parameter) {
            // String strval = select_parameter;
        String ret_val[] = null;
        String get_sel_val[] = null;    
        int loopcount =0;
        url = url+str_url;                                                                  //!!!! ######### CONCATINATING AND CREATING FULL URL ######## !!!!!!//
        Log.v("PROCESS QUERY PARAMETER","URL = "+url+" | PARAMTER = "+parameter);
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        //Log.i("STR VAL",""+strval);       //To Check which values are recieved
        try
        {
            String strval = parameter;
            get_sel_val=strval.split(delimiter1);

            for(int i =0; i < get_sel_val.length ; i++)     
            {

                loopcount = Integer.parseInt(get_sel_val[0]);           // First Delimeted Value which tells the number of count
                Log.i("Loopcount","cnt = "+loopcount);

            }

            for(int j=1;j<=(loopcount*2);j=j+2)                         //For Loop for making Name Values Pares Dynamic
            {
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(get_sel_val[j],get_sel_val[j+1]));
                //Log.i("J = ["+j+"]","pairvalue1 = "+get_sel_val[j]+"pairvalue2 ="+get_sel_val[j+1]);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.w("Exception in the getting value","Exp = "+e);
        }

        //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id","1"));

        try{
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                Log.v("CONNECT URL   ","Final url "+url);
                Log.w("CONNECTION STATUS ",httppost.toString());
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                Log.w("PAERSE VALUE ",nameValuePairs.toString());
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
                Log.w("1", "Connection establised succesfuly");
           }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
             Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
         }

         try{
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
                Log.v("SB VALUE = ","sb = "+sb.toString());
                String line="0";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
               is.close();
               result=sb.toString();

                //  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), result ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Log.w("result", result);
            }
          catch(Exception e)
          {
              Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
              Toast.makeText(null, "error converting response to string" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }

         String[] temp = null;
         String[] tempResult = null;

         if(result!=null)
         {
             tempResult = result.split(delimiter);                  //Split the entire return string into "rows"
             for(int i =0; i < tempResult.length-1 ; i++)       
              {
                 temp = null;   
                 temp = tempResult[i].split(delimiter1);        //Find columns for each row
                 ret_val = temp;
                 resultset_value=ret_val;
              }
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(null, "Cannot Find Routes" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

         Log.v("BEFORE RETUNR = ","ret_val = "+ret_val.toString());
         return ret_val;                                            //Returning the result value array
    }


                    /*************** PROCESS QUERY ENDS ***************/

      public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Activity activity) 
      {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity == null) 
        {
            return false;
        } 
        else
        {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null) 
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                    if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) 
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer this before posting a question : http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: In the line "Log.v("BEFORE RETUNR = ","ret_val = "+ret_val.toString());" you actually see something != null being printed? I would like to know that before I look at your code further..

Comment: Thanks for viewing my problem, Yes its giving me something like this
ret_val = [Ljava.lang.String;@40cd6b20
I am getting the expected value in onTaskComplete in the MainActivity, But the only thing what I am in need of is getting that result value in the MainActivity Class.
Could you please suggest me any solution for this.
Would be really thankful.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I tried my best to reduce it, but when I am trying to post my logcat over here its getting too long, is there any other way I can I post it?

Comment: you can post that on `http://pastebin.com/` and provide us the `URL`

Comment: @MehulJoisar Thank you so much, here is the Link : http://pastebin.com/Ag7nyB8w

Comment: @HimanshuSaxena: look at updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Because the statement written after the AsyncTask gets executes before getting the result.
```

the reason is [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) runs on separate thread,not on your Main(UI) thread.

```
MyTask extends Async Task and onPostExcute contains CallBackMethod which will return the result-set got from the doInBackground.
```

you will be getting result values on this method

```
   @Override
public void onTaskComplete(String[] result) {
    Log.v("IN ON TASK COMPLETE","VALUE = "+result[1]);


}
```

Comment following piece of code,

```
    if(asyncTask.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) || asyncTask.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.PENDING)) {
     asyncTask.execute();
 }
 else {

     Log.v("In Else","Get Value");
 }
```

Make change,

`public static String[] asyncResult;` to `public String[] asyncResult = null;`

Change following,

`asyncResultSetValue = Utils.process_query(params[0],params[1]);` to `asyncResult = Utils.process_query(params[0],params[1]);`
and `return asyncResultSetValue;` to `return asyncResult ;`

look at value by adding one more log,you will be getting result values on this method

```
   @Override
public void onTaskComplete(String[] result) {
    Log.v("IN ON TASK COMPLETE","VALUE = "+result[1]);
    Log.v("IN ON TASK COMPLETE","VALUE = "+asyncResult[1]);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for viewing my problem, yes I am recieveing the value in onTaskComplete method, but I want to access the result value in MainActivity, any idea how we can do that?

Thanks once again

Comment: I have updated my answer,now you have results in `asyncResult` .I'm glad to help you :-)

Comment: Thanks for your tips, I made the changes as you suggested, but really sorry to say its not working, 
It is giving me 
**Error : **  http connectionandroid.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
and NullPointerException on asyncResultSetValue

Comment: change `return asyncResultSetValue;` to `return asyncResult ;`

Comment: It tried in both the ways, I mean in main class and in OnTaskComplete Method but same error, NullPointerException.
sorry for disturbing again and again..

Comment: kindly post your logcat . so that i can suggest exact change

Comment: Thanks once again, here is the link of my new Logcat : http://pastebin.com/0JP5vfJL

Comment: can u update your question with the new changes?because the exception in logcat should not be there if you have done correct changes.

Comment: Hello @Mehul Joisar: I have updated my Question with the changes I have made in the MainActivity class
Here is the link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037922/asynctask-after-making-changes

Comment: man,I told to update,not to create new one.and why did you comment `MyTask asyncTask = (MyTask) new MyTask(this).execute("fetchCategory.php","1%Id%1");`?

Comment: and I told you to replace `syncResultSetValue = Utils.process_query(params[0],params[1]);` with `asyncResult = Utils.process_query(params[0],params[1]);`